# Reprocessing historical data on Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Let's say I have a simple DAG that creates/overwrites a number of daily tables: my_table_a_YYYYMMDD, my_table_b_YYYYMMDD, my_table_c_YYYYMMDD ....

It basically uses the BigQueryOperator to run SQL statements on a daily_basis for the current date, which is templated on the SQL file using the airflow [{{ ds }} variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html)

Assuming I just found out an issue with my .sql file, and after fixing I need to reprocess the last 10 days of execution. What is the best way to reexecute previous dag runs, fixing my tables?

Is it possible through Airflow UI, or I have to trigger the DAG remotely some way?

Answer (score 1):

As @Beppe C mentioned, you need to backfill your tables and Airflow provides an easy method of doing so.

Given the following DAG:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 12, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'schedule_interval': '@daily',
}

dag = DAG('tutorial', catchup=True, default_args=default_args)
```

This will run daily (`'schedule_interval': '@daily'`) starting on December 1st, 2015 (`'start_date':datetime(2015, 12, 1)`). If any logic changes are implemented and you want to backfill the table, make sure `catchup=True` is added to the DAG instantiation.

The documentation can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'Backfilling' concept. Your DAG has a start date, end date and schedule_interval, as soon as it is enabled Airflow will run the DAG to catch up (i.e. every day until today, or the end date)

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup